# AWS Lambda Post Requests Timeout Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda, timeout

I'm running Python on AWS Lambda. The code works fine with get requests, but when I try to post to a url it times out. I've tried the url with Postman and can post fine. Is there an obvious reason my POST Requests are timing out

```
import requests
import json


def lambda_handler(event=None, context=None):

    url = '[myurl]'
    myobj = {'somekey': 'somevalue'}

    x = requests.post(url, data=myobj)
    return x
```

Task timed out after 3.00 seconds

I've Tried increasing the timeout time but it still times out

Comment: Does this occur if you execute the code outside of Lambda?

Comment: When you increase the timeout, does it still timeout after 3 seconds? To what value did you increase the timeout?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the dev server has whitelisted certain ips, thus why it was working on local code and not server